# How to inject user data in $resource call?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I'm using $resource to fetch json data from a backend server.

First, I get a list of ids, with a first resource call. Then, for each id received, I use $resource to fetch data associated with this id.

Now, the problem is : I would like to associate the response with the id sent, so I can record data into a hashtable. (eg: $scope.table[response.id] = data; ). The only way I've found, is to have the API send back the id in the json response, but I'd like to associate the id with the query, so I know for which id is the response I got, without having the API to send it back.

Here is my current code (simplified, just to get the idea) :

```
// the factory. eg I send /rest/item/12345
app.factory('Item', function ($resource) {
    return $resource("/rest/item/:id", { id: '@id'})
});

// the call (in a loop)
// I need to get { "id" : 12345, "text" : "blahblahblah" } 
Item.get({ id : itemId },
  function(data){
    $scope.table[data.id] = data;
  });
```

I would like to write something like this :

```
// the call (in a loop). 
// I would like to only need to get { "text" : "blahblahblah" } 
Item.get({ id : itemId },
  function(id, data){
    $scope.table[id] = data;
  });
```

I guess I could use this form :

```
$scope.table[itemId] = Item.get({id : itemId});
```

But I need $scope.table[itemId] to be a "correct" value all the time, not a promise, and I want it to be updated just when I receive the answer.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this might work:

```
// get the array of ids
ItemIds.get({},
  function(ids){
    // for each id, make the request for the actual item
    ids.forEach(function(id) {
        Item.get({ id : id },
          function(data){
          // in this nested callback, you have access to data and id
          $scope.table[id] = data;
        });
    });
  });
```